# Creating terminal output from a JAR file

Tags: java, jar, cmd, executable-jar

I am creating a program that requires a input/output system, since this program doesn't have GUI, and I am launching it from a JAR file, I was wondering how I can create the input/output system.

Im starting to learn about JAR files, and normally I just run my finished program via a batch script. So how can I get this terminal like input/output system from a JAR? #beginner

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As there is no UI, you should run your program from Console (terminal) to use standard input/output. If you are in Window use (.bat) or if you are in linux use shell script(.sh) to call your jar

Comment: Thanks for the answer, I guess there is no way to someone create an input/output system via a jar if you have no GUI. This cleared up some confusion though, thanks :)

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if this is what you are asking for, but try this:

```
java -jar inout.jar
HELLO
gwag
Your input: gwag
faefa
Your input: faefa
feafa
Your input: feafa
faef
Your input: faef


public class Test {

public static void main(String[] args) throws InterruptedException {
    System.out.println("HELLO");
    Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);
    while(scanner.hasNext()) {
        System.out.println("Your input: " + scanner.next());
    }
}
```

}

Comment: It's a little more complicated that that, I was just dumbing down the question to get a broader answer range, but thanks though :)